# What is the hook to change the product gallery image size from 300*300 to actual image?

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, image-gallery

I am learning Woocommerce. I am on single product page and I am getting issue in product image.

[image]

My image size is `1000*1000` but I am getting `300*300`.

but when I hover on image then zoom is working perfectly and it's going end to end.
[image]

What hook I have to use to display the actual image for the product in single page gallery slider?

I tied below code but still I am not getting full image.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width'  => 900,
        'height' => 900,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
} );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an example of how you can override the woocommerce-single image:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_single', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width'  => 400,
        'height' => '',
        'crop'   => 0,
    );
} );
```

In this example, we’re setting the width to 400, the height to “automatic”, and we are not cropping the image by default.

If you wanted to set the image to a specific size and crop it to fit, you would do this:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_single', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width'  => 500,
        'height' => 500,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
} );
```

This snippet will change the woocommerce_thumbnail image to 500 x 500 pixels and crop the image.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width'  => 500,
        'height' => 500,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
} );
```

The snippet above will make the single product gallery images 400 x 400 pixels.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width'  => 400,
        'height' => 400,
        'crop'   => 1,
    );
} );
```

Comment: I tried your code but I don't know it's not working. Please check the screenshot https://i.ibb.co/NN3p28x/Screen-Shot-2021-02-18-at-11-57-40-PM.png I set the size 800*800

Comment: You can check this image. I tried horizontal also.  https://i.ibb.co/hdth77D/Screen-Shot-2021-02-19-at-12-03-18-AM.png

Comment: which code snippet have you used among given all?

Comment: To be very honest, I tried all one by one and  the second one the working

Comment: Great. It depends on filter which will be in use on the page you are referencing too